# mPDF auto print issue

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using a php class, mpdf, which generates PDF's very nicely.  I'm trying to get the file to automatically print (i.e., open the print dialog) when rendered.  I've extended the core functioning with the code below to add javascript to the pdf.  The pdf is rendered but without auto-printing. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
    require('mpdf.php');
    class PDF_JavaScript extends mPDF {
        var $javascript;
        var $n_js;

        function IncludeJS($script) {
            $this->javascript=$script;
        }
        function _putjavascript() {
            $this->_newobj();
            $this->n_js=$this->n;
            $this->_out('<<');
            $this->_out('/Names [(EmbeddedJS) '.($this->n+1).' 0 R]');
            $this->_out('>>');
            $this->_out('endobj');
            $this->_newobj();
            $this->_out('<<');
            $this->_out('/S /JavaScript');
            $this->_out('/JS '.$this->_textstring($this->javascript));
            $this->_out('>>');
            $this->_out('endobj');
        }
        function _putresources() {
            parent::_putresources();
            if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
                $this->_putjavascript();
            }
        }

        function _putcatalog() {
            parent::_putcatalog();
            if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
                $this->_out('/Names <</JavaScript '.($this->n_js).' 0 R>>');
            }
        }
    }
    class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_Javascript { 
        function AutoPrint($dialog=false) { //Embed some JavaScript to show the print dialog or start printing immediately
        $param=($dialog ? 'true' : 'false');
        $script="print($param);";
        $this->IncludeJS($script); } }


$mpdf = new PDF_AutoPrint('', 'Letter', 0, '', 12.7, 12.7, 14, 12.7, 8, 8);

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('eabill.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($message,2);
$mpdf->AutoPrint(true);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 21):

This works for me to print generated PDF file, i used it to print website page contents without menus, banners etc just content with own header and footer

```
$header = 'Document header';
$html   = 'Your document content goes here';
$footer = 'Print date: ' . date('d.m.Y H:i:s') . '<br />Page {PAGENO} of {nb}';

$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', 0, '', 12, 12, 25, 15, 12, 12);
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
$mpdf->SetJS('this.print();');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: The key here is using `$mpdf->SetJS('this.print();');` before sending the output. Thanks!

Comment: This solution rox, no need to add any files, just one line of code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried (snippet):

```
class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_Javascript { 
    function AutoPrint($dialog=false) {
      //Embed some JavaScript to show the print dialog or start printing immediately
      if( $dialog ){
        $script="this.print();";
        $this->IncludeJS($script);
      }
    }
```

Credit: [Create an Auto-Print PDF](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=157)

Or, taking the code from the second example in that article:

```
require('mpdf.php');

class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_Javascript { 
  function AutoPrint( $dialog=false ){
    if( $dialog ){
      $this->_newobj();
      $this->n_js=$this->n;
      $this->_out('<<');
      # Not sure whether this line is spot on, may need tweaking
      $this->_out('/OpenAction '.($this->n+2).' 0 R/Type/Catalog/Pages 1 0 R/PageMode/UseNone/PageLayout/OneColumn');
      $this->_out('>>');
      $this->_out('endobj');
      $this->_newobj();
      $this->_out('<<');
      $this->_out('/Type/Action/S/Named/N/Print');
      $this->_out('>>');
      $this->_out('endobj');
    }
  }
}


$mpdf = new PDF_AutoPrint('', 'Letter', 0, '', 12.7, 12.7, 14, 12.7, 8, 8);

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('eabill.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($message,2);
$mpdf->AutoPrint(true);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I tried both suggestions, but still no luck though.

Comment: @mozgras: I might have a play with this myself over the weekend. As I said, this code was adapted from something I read online, but had not tried myself, so I'll see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I use DTukans way + added false as a parameter.

Works in FireFox and IE - did not work for chrome :(

$mpdf->SetJS('this.print(false);');

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this as an external file and requested a print via javascript.

```
post_to_url("pdf.export.php", {htmlForPdf:pdf})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/903454