# Get Printers dialog when using mPDF instead of Save As dialog

Tags: php, printing, mpdf

I'm trying to find a way to open a "choose printer" dialog when the user push "print", in my PHP page, not the SaveAs window.

i read all posts here , couldn't find a reply that works.
also read this post :
[mPDF auto print issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169059/mpdf-auto-print-issue)

but the following code opens the saveas window, not the "choose printer" window:

```
$pdf=new mPDF('en','A4','','DejaVuSansCondensed',$template->margin_left,$template->margin_right,$template->margin_top,$template->margin_bottom,$template->margin_header,$template->margin_footer);
```

$pdf->setAutoFont();

$pdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);

$pdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

$pdf->SetJS('this.print();');

$pdf->writeHTML($printable);

$pdf->Output();

can anyone help?
why do i still get the "save as" window?

Answer (score 0):

To get a print dialog, you can simply use JS

```
window.onload = function() { window.print(); }
```

MPDF Functions:-
You can also use

```
<?php
// Saves file on the server as 'filename.pdf'
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hallo World</p>');
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');
?>
```

OR

ADD 'D' parameter to download it

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');
```

**Also REFER** [How to open print dialog after pdf generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733276/how-to-open-print-dialog-after-pdf-generated)

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't help me. window.print(); prints the page i'm in and it is not the PDF, it is another php page. i need to open a printer dialog to print the PDF, not the window. also calling Output with Parameters "D" or "F" is not relevant because i want to print the pdf , not save it as a file. as you can see above, i'm trying to print the PDF from the PHP code